# Set-theoretic definitions of sum and product with scalar of linear maps

Tags: definition

I use [these definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Forming_new_linear_maps_from_given_ones), but I need set-theoretic definitions because I define $h: A\to B \text{ for }\left\{\begin{array}{l} h \subseteq (A \times B) \\ \forall x,y,z:(((x,y) \in h \wedge (x,z) \in h) \to y=z) \\ \operatorname{dom}(h)=A \\ \operatorname{cod}(h)\subseteq B\end{array} \right.$

For example: $f_1 + f_2:=\{x|\exists y,z : (x=(y,z) \wedge y \in V \wedge z= f_1 + f_2)\}$ Is correct? If yes, I demonstrate $f_1 + f_2: V \to W$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f: V \to W$   and   $g: V  \to W$  are maps from a set $V$ to a set $W$  and  $\bot$  is  a law of  $W$, we ca define  $f \bot g$ by :

$$f \bot g: V \to W, x \mapsto f(x) \bot g(x)$$

If you want use the theoritic definition you can see $f$ as a part of $V \times W$  such that :$$(\star\star) \quad\left\{\begin{array}{l}(\forall x \in V)(\exists y \in W) \quad (x,y)\in f  \\  (\forall(x,y,y') \in V \times W  \times W)\quad  (x,y) \in f \wedge (x,y') \in f \Rightarrow y=y' \end{array} \right.$$

Then the définition of  $f+g$  is :

$$f+g=\{(x,y)/ (x \in V) \wedge (y \in W) \wedge  (y=y_1\bot y_2) \wedge ((x,y_1)\in f) \wedge ((x,y_2) \in g)\}$$

Comment: $y_1,y_2 \in V$?

Comment: @rag No, $y_1\in W \wedge y_2 \in W$. There  are defined by $(\star\star)$

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think you're being honest when you say you see a function like a subset of the cartesian product.  Because the example you gave is not a subset of any cartesian product.  What I think is that you have a homework problem to give a set-theoretic representation of the sum of two functions.

First, it's important to understand what it means to represent a function as a subject of the cartesian product of domain and target.  If $f\colon X \to Y$ is a function, we can create the set
$$
    R = \left\{(x,y) \mid f(x) = y \right\}
$$
Since $R\subset X\times Y$, this is a relation.  If $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and you plot $f$ in the plane, you see that $R$ is just the graph of $f$.

The defining property of a function is that its graph passes the “vertical line test”—that is, any vertical line intersects the graph in at most one point.  Let's translate that to a set-theoretic condition.  If the vertical line $x=x_0$ intersected the graph of $f$ in two points, then there would be two distinct points $(x_0,y_1)$ and $(x_0,y_2)$ on the graph of $f$.  That is, the points $(x_0,y_1)$ and $(x_0,y_2)$ would both be in $R$.  So $R\subset X\times Y$ is a function if there is no points $x_0$ and $y_1 \neq y_2$ with $(x_0,y_1)$ and $(x_0,y_2)$ in $R$.  Contrapositively, $R$ is a function if, for any points $x_0$, $y_1$, and $y_2$ with $(x_0,y_1)$ and $(x_0,y_2)$ in $R$, then $y_1 = y_2$.

Now to your problem.  You have $X$ and $Y$ vector spaces and two linear maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ from $X$ to $Y$.  Take a pair $(x_0,y_0)$ in $X\times Y$.  Under what conditions is $y_0=(f_1+f_2)(x_0)$?  It would have to be true that $y_0 = y_1 + y_2$ where $y_1 = f_1(x_0)$ and $y_2 = f_2(x_0)$.  In other words, $y_0 = y_1 + y_2$, where $(x_0,y_1)$ is in $R_{f_1}$, and $(x_0,y_2)$ is in $R_{f_2}$.